# Rearrange a list in BASH

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like:

file.dat

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 4
2 3
3 4
```

The left column is sorted. I would like to write a new file liek this:

```
1 2 3
2 1 4 3
3 4
```

In the first column should be the left column number of file.dat and next to it the right column numbers. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```awk
#!/bin/bash
awk -f <(cat - <<-'EOF'
  {
    b[$1, a[$1]++] = $2;
  }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "%d ", i;
      for (j = 0; j < a[i]; j++) {
        printf "%d ", b[i, j];
      }
      print ""
    }
  }
EOF
) < /dev/stdin
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh < file.dat 
1 2 3 
2 1 4 3 
3 4
```

This script will run with `awk`. Name if `file.awk`:

```awk
{
    b[$1, a[$1]++] = $2;
}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        printf "%d ", i;
        for (j = 0; j < a[i]; j++) {
            printf "%d ", b[i, j];
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Run like this:

```
 awk -f file.awk < file.dat
```

Comment: I created the awk script `file.awk` with your answer, then did `chmod +x file.awk` to make it excutable. How can I load the `file.dat` numbers?

Comment: The script above is a `bash` script. run it as `./script.sh < file.dat`.  Let me edit my answer so you can run it as an `awk` script.

Answer (score 3):

These answers don't require the whole file be stored in memory. They both require the file be sorted.

awk:

```
awk '
    $1 != prev {
        if (NR > 1) print ""
        printf "%d %d", $1, $2
        prev=$1
        next
    } 
    {printf " %d", $2} 
    END {print ""}
' file.dat
```

the equivalent bash:

```
prev=""
while read a b; do
    if [[ $prev != $a ]]; then
        [[ -n $prev ]] && echo
        printf "%d %d" $a $b
        prev=$a
    else
        printf " %d" $b
    fi
done < file.dat
echo
```

Answer (score 2):

well you have already your accepted answer. However I would like add another simpler (maybe)  short one-liner for your interesting problem.

```
awk '$1 in a{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2;next}{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

to see it worked with your example:

```
kent$  cat test.txt
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 4
2 3
3 4

kent$  awk '$1 in a{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2;next}{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' test.txt
1 2 3
2 1 4 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works

`awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]$2" "} END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}}' temp.txt`

Comment: Is this better than my answer six hours earlier? Presumably, the OP wants sorted output.

Comment: @steve I know your solution is always better and i don't argue that i just give give my answer based on the output. OP didn't mentioned that sorted output thing in question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ a[$1] = (a[$1] ? a[$1] FS : "") $2 } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] | "sort" }' file
```

Results:

```
1 2 3
2 1 4 3
3 4
```